# ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I understand that the issue is that the dimensions of the colour don't match the dimensions of the histogram input. However, I don't understand why.

This section of code works with no fault:

```
#Creates a histogram of zGRBs, comparing with old and new datasets  
zS = []
zM = []
plt.figure(1)

for i in range(len(GRBDict["GRBname"])):
    if GRBDict.get("Group")[i] == "S":
        zS += [GRBDict.get("z")[i]]
    elif GRBDict.get("Group")[i] == "M":
        zM += [GRBDict.get("z")[i]]

if len(zS) > 0:
    plt.hist(zS, np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 41), color="blue", label="Starling: " + str(Scount), alpha=0.8)
if len(zM) > 0:
    plt.hist(zM, np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 41), color="red", label="McGuire: " + str(Mcount), alpha=1)
if len(GRBDict["z"]) > 0:
    plt.hist(GRBDict["z"], np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 41), color="black", label="Total: " + str(Tcount), \
        alpha=0.6)

plt.xlabel("z")
plt.ylabel("N(z)")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")

plt.savefig(rootdir + "N(z)Hist.png", bbox_inches="tight")

plt.close()
```

But this section of code doesn't:

```
#Creates a histogram of spectral count  
SC = []
plt.figure(2)

with open(rootdir + "SpecLog.txt", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        SC += [line.split()[8]]

if len(SC) > 0:
    plt.hist(SC, np.linspace(0.0, 20000.0, 2001), color="green")

plt.xlabel("Spectral counts cts/s")
plt.ylabel("N(Spectral counts)")

plt.savefig(rootdir + "N(SC)Hist.png", bbox_inches="tight")

plt.close()
```

The problem must be staring me in the face but I don't see it, considering both histogram codes seem to be identical and yet I'm getting the colour kwarg error on the 2nd histogram.

I'm still new to python so apologies if this is really simple, I've already searched for this error but none of the issues seem to have helped.

Comment: You should really provide a minimal example, which we can reprocude (see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise I can only guess that the problem is exactly what the error message says: `SC` must have a different structure than `zS` and `zM`.

Comment: Have you googled this at all!? First hit leads here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757386/valueerrorcolor-kwarg-must-have-one-color-per-dataset 
I guess that this should solve your problem

Comment: i already looked at that hitzg, it doesn't help. SC has the same dimensions as zS or zM

Comment: Ok, same dimension. But maybe it is a list of lists?

Comment: Figured it out, as I thought it was a stupid error. I hadn't converted the values in SC to floats, so they were still strings.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid error as I suspected. Turned out it was because SC contained strings not numbers, so adding

```
 SC += [float(line.split()[8])]
```

was all that was needed to correct it.

Seems like the wrong type of error to present first though, as it didn't explain anything.

Thanks for you help.