# ValueError : "color kwarg must have one color per dataset" matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So, I got an  error when I compile my python code (matplot) which is :

> ValueError : color kwarg must have one color per dataset

The code which generates this error :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import pickle as pkl
from __future__ import division

sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.distplot(featureSet[featureSet['label']=='0']['len of url'],color='green',label='Benign URLs')
sns.distplot(featureSet[featureSet['label']=='1']['len of url'],color='red',label='Phishing URLs')
sns.plt.title('Url Length Distribution')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('Length of URL')

sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: What happens if you let seaborn choose the colour (ie leave the color parameter out)? Also sns.plt? I think should be just plt! Also could you the actual traceback so we can see which line the error came from.

Comment: @PaulaThomas Got the error on this line 
"sns.distplot(featureSet[featureSet['label']=='0']['len of url'],color='green',label='Benign URLs')".

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - please do not spam the tag (removed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: "color kwarg must have one color per dataset" matplotlib seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329965/valueerror-color-kwarg-must-have-one-color-per-dataset-matplotlib-seaborn)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError("color kwarg must have one color per dataset")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757386/valueerrorcolor-kwarg-must-have-one-color-per-dataset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `sns.plt`. Instead `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and use it directly.

Appart the code should run fine. I created the following minimal runnable example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"label" : np.random.randint(2, size=100).astype(str),
                    "data" : np.random.rayleigh(size=100)})

sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.distplot(df[df['label']=='0']['data'],color='green',label='Benign URLs')
sns.distplot(df[df['label']=='1']['data'],color='red',label='Phishing URLs')
plt.title('Url Length Distribution')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('Length of URL')

plt.show()
```

which produces the following output

[image]

If it does not work for you, consider upgrading your matplotlib and seaborn version. The above is produced with matplotlib 2.2.2 and seaborn 8.1.

Comment: I am having error on another function. That's why it still got error. But anyways thanks so I know where the problem lies in.

Comment: Why can't I use seaborn  library?

Comment: The example *does* use seaborn.

Answer (score -2):

Just delet color atribute.

Delete `color='green'` and `color = 'red'` and everything will work ok.

Comment: And if the user wants colors?